# implement rel="next and rel="prev" magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, pagination

im trying to get a paginated tags as rel="next" and rel="prev" for SEO reasons,
but i cant figure it out
ive tried this code in the `head.phtml`:

```
<?php
$actionName = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if ($actionName == 'catalog_category_view') // Category Page{
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$prodCol = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)));
$tool = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager')->setLimit($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getLimit())->setCollection($prodCol);
$linkPrev = false;
$linkNext = false;
if ($tool->getCollection()->getSelectCountSql()) {
  if ($tool->getLastPageNum() > 1) {
      if (!$tool->isFirstPage()) {
          $linkPrev = true;
          if ($tool->getCurrentPage() == 2) {
             $url = explode('?', $tool->getPreviousPageUrl());
            $prevUrl = @$url[0];
        }
        else {
            $prevUrl = $tool->getPreviousPageUrl();
        }
    }
    if (!$tool->isLastPage()) {
        $linkNext = true;
        $nextUrl = $tool->getNextPageUrl();
      }
   }
 }
 if ($linkPrev) echo '<link rel="prev" href="' . $prevUrl . '" />';
 if ($linkNext) echo '<link rel="next" href="' . $nextUrl . '" />';
}
?>
```

but for some reason its not showing any thing in the view source page.

please help im Frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```
if ($actionName == 'catalog_category_view') // Category Page{
```

Note that the opening bracket is after the comment start. (//).

This is probably causing a parse error, which you are not being shown.
You may want to turn on developer mode, which should give you information when this happens.

Change to this:

```
if ($actionName == 'catalog_category_view') { // Category Page
```

And you should get something as the page source.

Comment: ive changes the code as you suggested still nothing shows in the source. you can check the website if you like [link](https://www.shakedbeauty.com/cosmetics/holy-land.html?p=3)

Comment: @AlmogLahav, I see the link provided works.